# How to read the content in RestRequest

Tags: rest

I am passing a xml request and trying to read the req.requestBody but getting the value as Blob[2122]. How can I read the value which I have send for request in httppost. Please guide me.

Comment: You still have an open question here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69118/how-to-identify-what-type-of-request-is-coming/ surrounding this area that you haven't provided feedback to. I'm reluctant to provide further help to someone who doesn't seem to feedback into the community.

Comment: it because I did not reached to that steep. First I need to see the connect which have send for request. then only I cam move to the question which you have mention here. Yes will comment or accept the ans when I try try. For try that I need to reach to that steep. Hope you get me @mark